# Tensors with same name in the python code in tensorflow

Tags: variables, tensorflow, tensor

According to the code in: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py, it happens that the same names are used for the tensors variables such as:

```
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') # Under conv1, line: 208
```

and,

```
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(norm1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') # Under conv2, line 227
```

Therefore, why this is allowed in tensorflow? If for some reason, If I tried to say:

```
sess.run([conv], feed_dict{x: some_data})
```

Then which conv tensor we will be evaluated?

Second, if the **conv** tensor under **CONV1** layer was referring to the `tf.nn.conv2d` operation. How could another **conv** tensor under **CONV2** refer to the second `tf.nn.conv2d` operation? In other words, how they are treated separately?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: I think, all of those are under different namescopes. Their TF names are different. So, they don't conflict

Comment: @hars, Yea I totally agree with you. But from the coding perspective, how is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your question: latest "conv" is evaluated

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(5)
b = tf.constant(6)

c = tf.multiply(a,b)
print c
c = tf.multiply(c,b)
print c

sess = tf.Session()
c_val = sess.run(c)
print c_val
```

Output :

```
Tensor("Mul:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
Tensor("Mul_1:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
180
```

You can see TF names them differently. Whenever you call an TF operator, it creates a node independent of python variable name. But python variable name corresponds to latest tensor you used.

I hope this helps.